# How to avoid chroot jail affect actual system (e.g. update system time)?

Tags: linux, security, chroot, chroot-jail

I am new to chroot. I thought chroot is a contained separated system that would avoid things happen inside chroot jail affecting the actual system outside the jail. However I just confirmed that if I update the system time by `date -s` inside chroot, the system time of the actual system is also updated. This seems to me that it is not safe enough to jail untrusted executables inside the chroot.

Changing system configurations inside the jail affects the system outside the jail. Is it something that we need to concern about? Security breach? How to avoid that?

Comment: The chroot mechanism is not intended by itself to be used to block low-level access to system devices by privileged users.  Chroot is designed to re-root your filesystem to another path (thus chANGEroot).  I wouldn't try to use it for its "jail" properties.  If you are looking for that, I suggest a VM or docker.

Comment: Please go through [chroot tag-info](https://superuser.com/tags/chroot/info), it's really comprehensive.